# Crawling a list of URLS for specific links and Javascript

Tags: web-scraping

I have little experience with crawling and need help:

I have a **list of URLs** and I want to find out whether a certain tool is used on the websites.

The tool is working via an **iframe which is loaded when a link with a specific URL is clicked**.

So I am looking through the websites for this link. The problem I have is that sometimes this link is in an anchor element but sometimes **it is in a javascript function** (onclick on a button).

So the anchor element I can find (I tried around with different scraping frameworks like scrapy), but how do I find it when the link is in the function?

Is there an easier approach to the problem than looking for the -elements? E.g., downloading all html and all javascript and searching these files for the link? Because other than in classic crawling I do not want to extract structured data but rather know whether there is a specific link somewhere on the pages?

Thanks so much for any help or ideas!

Best
Martin

Comment: Show us you code, what have you tried until now? Also post a sample of such urls, and explain clearly what you are looking for in those pages.

Comment: Hi platipus, I tried (as I am new to web scrapping) Python-Selenium and could extraxt the anchor element with that. I also tried scrapy and could do the same (searching for HTML) elements. I have not tried to search for the javascript version (where the link is in the function because I do  not know how to approach it). What would really help me is: a) someone saying: do not waste your time searching for single elements and the JS but rather do xyz b) someone who knows how to search the javascript files for a specific link. I have done google research on all of that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.